# how to resize objects with resizing form using mouse

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am new to MFC and I am trying to change the size of my objects with respect to form. For this, I am using **single document** project and in **View.cpp** and **MainFrm.cpp** I have changed form size.

```
  BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    if( !CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
        return FALSE;
    // TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
    //  the CREATESTRUCT cs
    cs.cx = 400;
    cs.cy = 400;
    return TRUE;
}
```

and in View.cpp, I have fixed the initial size of screen as given below.

```
BOOL CDCDrawingView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    // TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
    //  the CREATESTRUCT cs
    cs.cx = 400;
    //const wchar_t a = cs.cx;
    width = cs.cx;
    cs.cy = 400;
     height = cs.cy;
    return CView::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

Here comes the problem, I want to draw the objects and I want to change the size of those objects with respect to size of form by using mouse. The form is able to change its size but I dont know how to update the form coordinates. I have attached the initial form and and form after changing size by mouse.
initial form is given below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQOsf.jpg)
and form after changing size by mouse is given below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbBpi.jpg)
could someone please tell me how to change the objects with resizing form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To solve this problem, get main window size by using
//Get main window size
 CRect rect;
 GetClientRect(&rect);

Comment: @IInspectable, it is not the same post anyway, and here is the answer I added in comments.

Comment: It is a duplicate. And if you follow the answers you'll find that you do not need to call `GetClientRect`. Your [OnSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onsize) handler already receives the parameters that reflect the new client area size.